# Empty php variable after ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, deployment

I have the following code in my script file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "server.php?saveEvent",
    data: "myEvent=" + JSON.stringify(myEvent),
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $("#log").append("<br />Evenement saved.");
        }
    }
});
```

In server.php I retrieve the variable using:

```
if (isset($_GET['saveEvent'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['myEvent'])) {
        $firephp->log(gettype($_POST['myEvent']));
        $myEvent = json_decode($_POST['myEvent'], true);
    }
}
```

When I tested this on my localhost, everything went fine. Unfortunately, after deployment,
    $myEvent
was empty.

Using firephp, I tested what was in the variable, and I looked at the headers being sent. The object was sent to the server, but still somehow php see's it as being an empty variable.

Any ideas on how this is possible? Is it a php version or json issue?

EDIT: PHP ver= 5.2.17 / json enabled

EDIT2: Changing te url to ?saveEvent=1 didnt change anything

Edit3: I realize making a get and post is a bit strange, I'll try changing that, but get/post shouldn't be a problem I think

Comment: What version of php do you have installed? It might be that you do not have the json extension enabled

Comment: You are making a post request but have a get condition on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your uri contains a *GET* parameter, `saveEvent`. You're checking for `POST` data only

try checking this: `$_GET['saveEvent']`

Even so, that parameter hasn't got a value assigned to it, perhaps change the url to `?saveEvent=1`.
There's also no reason for you to use 2 if statements:

```
if (isset($_GET['saveEvent'] && isset($_POST['myEvent']))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Since it seems there's more going on than just the `GET` vs. `POST` issue, you might want to add an ampersand (`&`) at the end of your url: look at your console, the XHR request just pastes the POST parameters at the end of your url, so the uri will look like either one of the following urls:

```
server.php?saveEvent=truemyEvent=foo
server.php?saveEvent=1myEvent=foo
server.php?saveEventmyEvent=foo
//or
server.php?saveEvent=1?myEvent=foo
```

Whereas, what you need is:

```
    server.php?saveEvent=1&myEvent=foo&something=else
```

Basically, stick to 1 method, either POST or GET, and make sure that the various parameters are separated as they're supposed to be separated.
I'm not sure if this is the issue, but try `var_dump`-ing the `$_REQUEST` super-global, along with `$_GET`, `$_POST` and what have you...

Comment: @Tim: what solved it eventually? was it a missing ampersand, or something else all together?

Comment: yes, the ampersand seemed to help, although its confusing since post data should be in the body. I also got rid of the extra get parameters.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a bit confusing, but try to look at the headers in firebug/chrome dev-tools: even a post request will look like this: `someurl/?param=value&some=more&params=too`...

Answer (score 1):

Is the behavior of using just `server.php?saveEvent` well defined by your server? The behavior of doing that may vary between servers or versions of PHP. What would the PHP variable be set with? It isn't exactly clear using that shorthand, so I would be nervous using `isset()` like you are. I would use something more ordinary like `server.php?saveEvent=true` so that you're sure `saveEvent` is going to be set.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an object instead of a string in your data

```
data: {myEvent:myEvent},
```